# Cannot get Spring MVC 3.2.4 to serve jsp with UrlBasedViewResolver

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, url-routing

When I put `System.out.println` on my `@Controller`, i see message in Tomcat console, but web browser gives me `The requested resource () is not available.`

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexPageController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String homePage(Model model) {
        System.out.println("Controller method called"); // gets printed
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

My view resolver (in XML related to this URL dispatcher):

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

ViewResolver is created for sure, because it throws exception about viewClass if I remove this required property.

Of course, there exists `/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp` file. Also this file is deployed corretly (checked tomcat runtime directories).

Don't see any exception in `tomcat_working_dir/logs`, only access log with:

`127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2013:13:59:01 +0100] "GET /mvctest/hello HTTP/1.1" 404 952`

returning "hello.jsp" from controller doesn't change anyting.

Invoking other URL than `/hello` gives excatly the same output `` `The requested resource () is not available. ``

**It looks that `JstlView` forwards to JSP through `DispatcherServlet` AGAIN and of course dispatcher doesn't know mapping for such URL**

Spring LOG:

```
14:20:43.049 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-16] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'hello'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'
14:20:43.049 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-16] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'hello'
14:20:43.049 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-16] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher' processing GET request for [/mvctest/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp]
14:20:43.050 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-16] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp
14:20:43.050 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-16] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp]
14:20:43.050 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-16] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mvctest/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'
```

`TRACE`-leveled log here: [pastebin raw file](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=c83dnmks).

`web.xml` dispatcher config:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

There are no others `servlets` nor `servlet-mapping`s, only `welcome-file-list`.

Comment: Please post your server-side exception log. Also, what happens if you return `"hello.jsp"`?

Comment: @chrylis Added informations

Comment: Turn on logging for `DispatcherServlet` with at least `INFO` level, and you should get a useful error message in the Spring logs (which you may have configured to go to a different place than the Tomcat container logs).

Comment: Did that, i see that request to my jsp is forwarded through dispatcherservlet aganin without succefful mapping found. Adding log to question

Comment: I think your dispatcher servlet is misconfigured. Could you post the  relevant part from web.xml?

Comment: @gadget Added web.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is coming from your dispatcher servlet mapping. It intercepts requests to your jsp as well because of the '/*' mapping. It should be:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: So small mistake, so much problems.